# How to program shortcut for website with j2me and netbeans?

Tags: blackberry, netbeans, java-me

I want make application for my blackberry ..

the application is .. shortcut for my website .. like when I'm click he go to my website .

Answer (score 1):

The BlackBerry knowledge center has a guide ["How To - Create a web icon"](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800440/How_To_-_Create_a_web_icon.html?nodeid=1487655&vernum=0) that provides the code to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can start reading some tutorials from [Netbeans Docs & Support](http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/mobility.html) section on Java ME